# Insert value automatically in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table named `income_table` and I have to insert one row automatically  every month but I don't know how to insert a value automatically in the database.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a [MySQL Event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/event-scheduler.html), I believe it's the simplest way nowadays. If you have **phpmyadmin**, no code is required besides the `INSERT` statement:

- click on the database you want to create the event and on the top bar click the "Events" link;
- turn on the scheduler by clicking the button on that page;
- add a new event and set it to "recurring" on the pop up window;
- choose the remaining options as you need;
- add the insert statement in the text area on that same window;
- click the "Go" button and it's done!

Btw, the generated code from that event can be exported later and will look something like this:

```
CREATE EVENT `monthly`
 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH
 STARTS '2015-10-07 00:00:00'
 ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE
 DO INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a cron that will run every month and that will insert the row every month.

Comment: Cron is just one of the many posibilities to schedule the running of an sql statement.

Comment: can you give me the code for this please..

Answer (score 0):

You either use a scheduler outside of the database like cron or windows task scheduler to run a batch with an sql command using [mysql's command line utility](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/command-line-options.html), or you can use [mysql event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/event-scheduler.html) to schedule the execution of an sql statement within mysql.

Answer (score -1):

You need to run cron for every month that will insert the value into the database.