# execute query on a specific time

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have an MySQL database with 3 tables, 
table 1 with the current price of milk, table 2 with the current price of bread.
Every 10 minutes there's a new row in both tables with the new price.

In the 3th table i have the average price of milk and the average price of bread of each single day. 
Now i need code to execute the insert-query of the average prices every day (at 00:01).
Is this possible? and of so, how? with a trigger? a stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the event scheduler what you are looking for?
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html

> An event performs a specific action according to a schedule. This action consists of an SQL statement, which can be a compound statement in a BEGIN ... END block if desired (see Section 14.6, “Compound-Statement Syntax”). An event's timing can be either one-time or recurrent.

Comment: MySQL 5.7+ Only answer

Comment: Good point. @Jelle what version on MySQL are you using? Did you see the following post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971461/insert-value-automatically-in-database/32971648#32971648